# run cron job between 00:00 - 00:02 - 04:00 - 23:59 on every hour

Tags: cron

I want to run a cron job between 0:00am - 02:00am - 04:00am and 23:59am on every hour.

I want to know if this is the correct syntax.

0,0-59 0-2,4-23/1 * * *

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, your syntax is not correctly formatted.

You can use:

```
0 0 0/1,0-2 ? * *
```

This will run according to the following rules:

```
At second :00, at minute :00, every hour between 00am and 02am, 
  and every hour starting at 00am, of every day
```

You can check CRON syntax with an explanation at:[Cron Expression Generator & Explainer](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html).

Also, I think [this site](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/crontrigger.html) has a really good breakdown to help understand what each section of the CRON expression relates to.

**Edit**: I just noticed you had the second part about running at 23:59. For this you will need to set up a second CRON job:

```
0 59 23 * * ? *
Use Case: At 23:59:00pm every day
```

Comment: I added a second part to this, it looks like I missed the 23:59 part in the initial answer. You will need a second job for that part.

Comment: Did you have other questions or did this work for you?